How to install virtual-select with npm On laravel 11 site
On Laravel 11 site I try to use virtual-select installed with npm.
After npm install I tried do it in usual way with valid path of files in app.js:
import VirtualSelect from 'virtual-select-plugin/dist/virtual-select.min.js'
import 'virtual-select-plugin/dist/virtual-select.min.css'

But when I try to use VirtualSelect in my Blade file :
                VirtualSelect.init({
                    ele: '#userPermissionSelection',
                    multiple: true,
                    showValueAsTags: true,
                    tooltipFontSize: 16,
                    options: @json($userPermissionsSelectionItems),
                    selectedValue: @json($selectedFilterUserPermissions),
                    allowNewOption: true,
                    additionalClasses: ''
                });

I got error :

app.js:12 Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/virtual-select-plugin_dist_virtual-select__min__js.js?v=e4b4e9f8' does not provide an export named 'default' (at app.js:12:9)

Also I tried to use way as I read here :
https://sa-si-dev.github.io/virtual-select/#/?id=get-started

and in my Blade file wrote :
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/virtual-select-plugin/dist/virtual-select.min.css">
<script src="/node_modules/virtual-select-plugin/dist/virtual-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- optional -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/tooltip-plugin/dist/tooltip.min.css">
<script src="/node_modules/tooltip-plugin/dist/tooltip.min.js"></script>

But another errors :
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/node_modules/virtual-select-plugin/dist/virtual-select.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

staff-users:34
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/node_modules/tooltip-plugin/dist/tooltip.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

staff-users:31
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/node_modules/virtual-select-plugin/dist/virtual-select.min.js 404 (Not Found)

staff-users:35
   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/node_modules/tooltip-plugin/dist/tooltip.min.js

That is some strange way to show link to node_modules dir. Which way is correct ?
    "sweetalert2": "^11.12.1",
    "virtual-select-plugin": "^1.0.44"

    "laravel/framework": "^10.48.12",
    "livewire/livewire": "^3.5.0",

